# How to convert a JavaScript array to an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am having an array of arrays in Javascript, like

```
[
    ["2019","abc","xyz"],
    ["2014","DEF","PQR"]
]
```

How can I convert the above array into array of objects like,

```
[
    {
        date: 2019,
        name:abc,
        address:xyz
    },
    {
        date: 2014,
        name: DEF,
        address: PQR
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Array.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to build desired format, here i am [**Destructuring**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) element from each array as `date, name, and address` and than returning an object with these `key/value` pair

```js
let data =  [["2019","abc","xyz"],["2014","DEF","PQR"]]

let op = data.map(([date, name, address]) => ({date, name, address}))

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let arr = [["2019","abc","xyz"],["2014","DEF","PQR"]];
let result = arr.map(([data,name,address]) => ({data, name, address}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple routine

```js
var arr = [["2019","abc","xyz"],["2014","DEF","PQR"]];

var output = [];

arr.forEach(function(el){

    output.push({
        date: el[0],
        name: el[1],
        address: el[2]
    });
});

console.log(output)
```

Comment: You can create a running code snippet [read here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)